# Simplifying/Finding the natural log of two terms without logarithm laws.

Tags: logarithms

If there's a natural log of two terms, which I cannot simplify with the laws of logarithms, how should I simplify it?

e.g. $\ln(e^{6x} + 17)$

The full equation could be something like this: 
$$\ln(e^{2x}) + \ln(e^{6x} +17) = \ln(50).$$

I know that I can simplify $\ln(e^{2x})$ to just $2x,$ and I can evaluate $\ln(50)$ with a calculator. But I'm not sure how to simplify the $\ln(e^{6x} + 17).$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your questions.

Comment: Take base e of both sides of that equation, then use exponent properties and log properties to simplify

Comment: Eliminate logarithms completely, by taking exponential of both sides.

Answer (score 1):

$$\ln(e^{2x})+\ln(e^6x+17)=\ln(e^{2x}(e^{6x}+17))=\ln(50) \Rightarrow \\
t(t^3+17)=50 \Rightarrow t=2\\
e^{2x}=2 \Rightarrow x=0.5\ln 2.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\ln (e^{2x})+\ln (e^{6x}+17) = \ln 50$$
As you know, $$\log_a b+\log_a c = \log_a (bc)$$

$$\ln\big[(e^{2x})(e^{6x}+17)\big] = \ln 50$$
Remove the log from both sides.

$$(e^{2x})(e^{6x}+17) = 50$$
Now, replace $e^{2x}$ with a variable so it can be solved easily.
$$m = e^{2x}$$
$$m(m^3+17) = 50$$
$$m = 2$$
$$e^{2x} = 2$$
$$2x = \ln 2 \implies \boxed {x = \frac{\ln 2}{2}}$$